# Javascript Not Setting Cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, javalin

I'm trying to set cookies using Javascript. This code had been working up until recently, when I started getting `null` for the value of the cookies. I'm really not sure what I could've changed to cause this. Here is my `HTML`:

```
  <div class="w3-container w3-center" style="align-content:center;">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1 class="w3-center w3-jumbo">Find a Fruit Here</h1>
      <form method="post" name="input-form" id="input-form" class="w3-center w3-mobile">
        <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width:1000px;align-content:center;">
          <label>Address</label>
        </h4>
        <input id="input-address" style="max-width:300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" class="w3-center w3-input w3-border" name="Address" placeholder="123 45th Street, City, State" required>          
      
        <h4 class="w3-center" style="max-width:1000px;">
          <label>Fruits(at least one)</label>
        </h4>
        <input id="input-items" style="max-width:300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" class="w3-center w3-input w3-border" name="Items" placeholder="Apples, bananas, etc." required>
        <h4>
          <button style="max-width:250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round w3-hover-light-grey w3-center" type="submit" onclick="cookies()">
            Search
          </button>
        </h4>
      </form>      
      <br>
  </div>
```

And this is my Javascript. I've added a logging line to test, but that never gets printed to the console, so I figured I might have a problem calling the function.

```
<script>

function cookies() {
  document.getElementById("input-form").submit();
  document.cookie = "address=" + document.getElementById("input-address").value.replaceAll(",", "/");
  document.cookie = "items=" + document.getElementById("input-items").value.replaceAll(",", "/");
 }

</script>
```

Any help is really appreciated!! I'm at a loss.

EDIT:
I'm accessing my cookies in a Java program using Javalin, and that's where I'm seeing that they're null. I'm rendering the document in Javalin and then trying to access the cookies, then getting a NullPointerException. Here is the Java code:

```
app.get("/search", ctx -> ctx.render("/donation-find.html"));
app.post("/search", ctx -> {
   ctx.render("/donation-find.html");
   address = ctx.cookie("address").replaceAll("/", ",");
   String[] temp = ctx.cookie("items").split("/");
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the above HTML and JavaScript is interacting with Javalin? Is this running in a browser that's communicating with a Java web server, and Javalin is part of the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarification purposes, I ended up solving the problem by using an entirely different method of transferring data. Instead of using cookies, I just used the Javalin built-in method `formParam(key)` to access the data posted to the form

Answer (score 1):

you are submiting the form before updating the cookies on the Javascript.
So the actual POST request is sent before the cookies update
I think you should Just do that

```
function cookies() {
  document.cookie = "address=" + document.getElementById("input-address").value.replaceAll(",", "/");
  document.cookie = "items=" + document.getElementById("input-items").value.replaceAll(",", "/");
 }
document.getElementById("input-form").submit();
```

I think that will help
I dont know how it was working before 
Best guess is it was pulling the old session cookies

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer because it did help but I was able to solve my problem a different way

Comment: Thanks, Can you please show how you did solve the problem??

Comment: Yeah, I just posted a new answer.